# cancan rspec unexpected behavior while testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, cancan

i'm testing cancan abilities according with this guide: [link](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Testing-Abilities)

this is my ability file: 
***UPDATED:***   i have posted all ability file.

```
#models/ability.rb
class Ability
include CanCan::Ability

def initialize(user)
user ||= User.new(role:Role.find_by(name:'guest')) # in case of guest

if user.has_role? :admin
  can :manage, :all
end

if user.has_role? :author
  can :read, :all
  can :create, Msg
  can :create, Post
  can :destroy, Msg, user_id:user.id 
  can :destroy, Post, user_id:user.id 
  can :update, Post, user_id:user.id
  can :update, Msg, user_id:user.id
  can :destroy, Msg, post: { user_id:user.id }
end

if user.has_role? :moderator
  can :read, :all
  can :create, Msg
  can :destroy, Msg
  can :update, Msg ,    user_id:user.id
end

 if user.has_role? :guest
   can :read, Msg
   can :read, Post
 end

if user.has_role? :user
  can :read, :all
  can :create, Msg
  can :destroy, Msg , user_id:user.id 
  can :update, Msg , user_id:user.id 
end
end
```

this is my spec test:

```
require "cancan/matchers"
require 'spec_helper'

describe "when is moderator" do
 before do
   @u=FactoryGirl.create(:moderator)
   @p=FactoryGirl.create(:post,user_id: 1245)#To be sure @p don't belongs to @u
   @a=Ability.new(@u)
 end

it{ @a.should be_able_to(:update, Post) } #Ok, it must be pass
it{ @a.should be_able_to(:update, FactoryGirl.create(:post,:user_id => @u.id)) } #Ok, it must be pass
it{ @a.should be_able_to(:update,@p) } #passed, ***but should fail***
end
```

I have no idea to solve, in my opinion this behavior is unattened

Comment: This does not solve your problem, but you should write your tests so that, when your app is working correctly, they will all pass. So in this case, you should use the method `should_not` rather than `should` for the third assertion.

Comment: If my ability are correct the third assertion must be fail, i think.

Comment: post all `ability.rb`

Comment: i have posted all ability.

Comment: Have you inspected to see that `@p.user_id` is in fact `1245` (i.e. that your factory is working as expected)?

Comment: yes, i have just try to do this inspection.

Comment: Solved: the problema was in my factories. Now i have correct the factories